# malloc error in Assembly language (MASM)

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I'm trying to make macro named "malloc"(memory allocation) on Assembly language.

Then Here is my code as following.
When I debug the code, at line 34 "ret 4", I got an error "Source not available".
And at call stack window on Visual Studio, I saw the message
"   [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for ntdll.dll] " too.

How could I fix the error?
I had no idea the reason why the error comes up.

```
TITLE project6 (project6.asm)

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

malloc          MACRO           aSize
                push            aSize
                call            alloc
ENDM

.data
array_size = 10
hHeap               HANDLE          ?
str1                BYTE "Heap size is: ",0

GetProcessHeap      PROTO

.code

alloc               PROC
                    push            EBP
                    mov             EBP,ESP
                    sub             ESP,4                ; create a space for dealing HEAP_HANDLE                       

                    INVOKE          GetProcessHeap                                          
                        .IF         eax == NULL                                         
                         call       WriteWindowsMsg
                         jmp        quit
                        .ELSE
                         mov        hHeap, eax                                          
                    .ENDIF

                    add             esp, 4                   ; clean up the stack                           
                    pop             ebp
                    ret             4

                    quit:           exit
alloc               ENDP

main                PROC
                    malloc          array_size

main                ENDP
                    END             main
```

The "alloc" procedure allocates size bytes from the heap and returns the address of the allocated space in memory. Arguments to this procedure should be passed via the stack.

Thanks

Comment: "allocates size bytes from the heap" - Are you sure? Windows GetProcessHeap function doesn't allocate memory (see the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366569(v=vs.85).aspx)). As for your other problem, my two best guesses are "source doesn't match executable" and "stack getting mucked up."  When you run this under the debugger, are you using the "Disassembly" window?  And are you walking the code with "step into" or "step over"?  As a test, you can try replacing `ret 4` with `pop ecx` `ret`.  If I'm reading this right, ecx should be array_size.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd : The size is pushed in the malloc macro before `call alloc` so not sure how `pop ecx; ret` would work given that the size was palced on the stack before the call.

Comment: Only other thing I noticed is that the code doesn't actually do an ExitProcess or some other method to close down the program. Possibly because the `quit:           exit` is in the wrong place and should have appeared at the end of `main`.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd Thank you for the reply. I'm working the code with "Step into" and "Step over." Besides it, I opened "Disassembly" window. But I had no idea how I could find where the problem is on the window. 
Then I tried to ask the question here. Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I tried to put the quit: exit at the end of main before I put the question here. But an error came up that was A2006: undefined symbol : quit. Then I put quit: exit to the current place.

Comment: Still think your issues are related to executing code beyond the end of the program, would explain the source not being available after the last known instruction. I'd guess it might even be stopping on `cc` (int 3h debug interrupt). Here is my recommendation. Remove the line `jmp        quit` and replace with `exit`. Then after `malloc          array_size` add `exit` (exit is a macro that will invoke ExitProcess). Remove the line `quit:           exit` entirely

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thanks. It worked. My mistake was not to put "exit" to main. I thought How careless mistake I did.. Thanks anyway. It was really good help to advance my homework !

Comment: As you are using macros, disassembly view would be quite crucial for me to see, what is actually being executed (macros tend to be quite confusing to me, as they hide the actual instructions). YMMV.